# slitaz cooking grub2 loopback

Tags: boot, grub2, usb-drive, slitaz

I'm trying to get slitaz cooking ISO to boot using a grub2 loopback on a multiboot USB;

```
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg
insmod font
if loadfont /boot/grub/unicode.pf2 ; then
    insmod efi_gop
    insmod efi_uga 
    insmod gfxterm
    insmod vbe
    insmod vga
    set gfxmode=auto
    set gfxpayload=auto
    terminal_output gfxterm 
    if terminal_output gfxterm; then true ; else
        terminal gfxterm
    fi
fi

menuentry "Slitaz Cooking" {
    set isofile="/boot/slitaz-cooking.iso"
    loopback loop $isofile
    linux (loop)/boot/bzImage lang=en kmap=us isofrom=$isofile boot=live noeject noprompt root=/dev/null
    initrd (loop)/boot/rootfs.gz
}
```

tried with `screen=text` and `screen=1024x768x24` kernel options but it never gets to a useable gui/terminal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
menuentry "Slitaz 3.0" {
    set isofile="/boot/slitaz-3.0.iso"
    loopback loop $isofile
    linux (loop)/boot/bzImage lang=en kmap=us autologin isofrom=$isofile boot=live noeject noprompt root=/dev/null
    initrd (loop)/boot/rootfs.gz
}
```

Ended up being an issue with the currently available version of cooking, downloaded the 3.0 iso and it boots fine in grub2 loopback

Answer (score 0):

That entry looks correct, although I've never had to add `isofrom=$isofile`.  I will mention that I've had the exact same problem booting from my Asus netbook, but not from other computers.  And The boot froze around initramfs, not all the way at X.

I suggest you try and boot this off other computers, which would suggest we encountered the same problem.

Comment: just tried a different machine, displays boot process then monitor goes into powersave and machine is unresponsive ...

Answer (score 0):

As of December 2018, I was able to use a slightly modified version of Thermionix's answer to boot a `slitaz-rolling.iso` file.  My host system is Lubuntu 18.10 with an `ext4` filesystem.

I added the following to `/etc/grub.d/40_custom`:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec tail -n +3 $0
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.

menuentry "SliTaz Rolling 20181204" {
  set isofile="/home/[USER]/slitaz-rolling.iso"
  loopback loop $isofile
  linux (loop)/boot/bzImage lang=en kmap=us autologin isofrom=$isofile boot=live noeject noprompt root=/dev/null
  initrd (loop)/boot/rootfs4.gz (loop)/boot/rootfs3.gz (loop)/boot/rootfs2.gz (loop)/boot/rootfs1.gz
}
```

After editing `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` I ran:

```
$ sudo update-grub
$ sudo shutdown -r now
```

I was then able to select `SliTaz Rolling 20181204` from the Grub2 menu and boot into SliTaz.